# Is there a way I can add a WordPress plugin to my hand coded HTML site?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to use the 'Ultimate member' WordPress plugin since building that kind of system is a bit tedious.

Comment: Are you asking if you can use a Wordpress plugin on a non-Wordpress website? If so, the answer is no. System-specific software only builds on the existing functionality of the system, it doesn’t recreate it all from scratch so it can’t be used separately.

Comment: [This might be what you're looking for? Tell me if that's helping](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/)

Comment: And also [MerlinWP](http://merlinwp.com/) which is also really popular

Comment: @amarinediary they still require a Wordpress site, they only help with theme and plugin setup. A plugin doesn’t have the standard CMS functionality that Wordpress provides - it uses WP for that functionality and just adds to it. It also uses WPs database. For example, the Ultimate Member plugin on its own doesn’t have the underlying framework for users, roles, permissions, user management etc, or it’s own database to store any of that information.

Comment: Sorry didn't understood the question @FluffyKitten. He was talking about a website outside of the wordpress environment and no CMS, so you're right.

Comment: @amarinediary well the question isn't very clear in the first place, so I can understand getting it wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.

As others have pointed out, plugins rely heavily on Wordpress' architecture and functionality for their own functionality.

You may be able to find a service which offers an API for account creation and authentication, but chances are you'll be using custom content for your users, which you'll need a server-side language like PHP (used by Wordpress) for.

Wordpress really isn't too much of a pain to set up, and if you have all the HTML, CSS and JS files complete, you can throw it together in a few hours.

If playing around in WP code *really* is not for you, there's even plugins to do it for you. Just complete the "5 minute setup" and away you go.

Comment: Sam as a point @Lightcode, converting a static website to a wordpress one is pretty easy nowadays and would be the fastest way to solve your problem.